# Joomla: change the content of a page before redirecting to it

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to add a form to my website for search. upon submit the user will be redirected to a page with search results.

I am processing the form in a php file that redirects to results page. I am thinking of different approaches to populate the results page:

- already populate the page with all the possible results, and pass the a CSS or JS when redirecting to hide the irrelevant items.
- prepare all the possible results and store them in the database or and append them to the search result page before redirecting.

I am new to joomla so I am not sure which solution would be better and how should I start implementing it.

or maybe there is another Joomla!-like way to do it?
Thank you !